# how to set the min point length if the data is greater than zero in bar graphs of highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

[image]There are two items, if i set the minPointLength then if the data from the first item is not zero but less and if the data for the second item in zero then on hover we can only see the data for the second item which is zero and cant see the data of first item.So i wanna set this minPointLength for the data which is greater than zero and also add some padding below so that i can also hover and see the item with data zero.
My code is

```
   plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    animation: 1000,
                    groupPadding: 0.5,
                    pointWidth: 45,
                    minPointLength: 3,
                    series: {
                        stickyTracking: true
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function( e ) {
                            $( e.browserEvent.currentTarget ).find( '.graph__legend' ).toggleClass( 'graph__legend--muted' );
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Where you say `...data which is greater than zero`, do you you mean **less than** zero instead? As you have not mentioned a data set which is greater than 0 previously

Comment: Am I correct in assuming, the 1st item > 0 and 2nd item = 0?

Comment: Creating a fiddle which demonstrates the problem would help everyone understand the issue here.

Comment: Being honest I was not able to replicate your issue. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmg62cy6/. Could you update my code with yours to introduce the issue?

Comment: I am not able to replicate it on the fiddle but i will try to clear. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmg62cy6/1/ . Now please try to collaborate the two bars in one like one stacking on another. iam attacking a screen shot of how it should look @SebastianBochan

Comment: Yes my friend @wmash

Comment: I am unsure as to what you are asking. In your question, you mention 2 items. Item 1 > 0 and Item 2 = 0. However, later in the question you say you want to set **minPointLength** for the data which is greater than 0 (which you have not mentioned yet) and want to also see the item where data = 0? Nowhere do you mention that you wan to view the data which is **less then** 0 (Item 1). Also, on your jsFiddle, your only data is **greater than** 0 with no negative values at all. I can't seem to understand your question

Comment: You really need to set up a fiddle with your actual options, and the actual data that you are referring to, so we can see the problem that you're talking about.